# Who did have vs who had

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I want to make wh question from the sentence "John had lunch".

I want to know which is correct:

1- Who had lunch?

2- Who did have lunch?

Comment: What is  wh question for you? Please explain: what,who,which, when

Comment: Who, I explained that in the next line!

Comment: So, you want to create a sentence with the pronoun who. A wh question is inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two distinct questions can be formed here:

1. *"Who had lunch?"*  This is a straightforward question, given no other context than wanting to know who had lunch.

   > **Alice:** Who had lunch?
   >
   > **Bob:** John had lunch.
2. *"Who did have lunch?"*  This question requires an initial premise suggesting that fewer people had lunch than were expected.  In speech, **did** would be emphasised.

   > **Bob:** Not many people had lunch, most people just chatted amongst themselves.
   >
   > **Alice:** Who *did* have lunch?
   >
   > **Bob:** John had lunch.

Both are correct, depending on the context.

Comment: **did** here is an auxiliary used for emphasis. But I agree with your answer.